# Aligning boxes in a table (calendar)

Tags: html, css, calendar

I am working on a calendar set up and implemented it using a table. However, I am struggling to get the boxes to fill the calendar. My html currently looks like this:

```
<div id="cal">
    <div class="header">
      <span class="left button" id="prev"> &lang; </span>
      <span class="month-year" id="label"> June 2017 </span>
      <span class="right button" id="next"> &rang; </span>
    </div>
    <table id="days">
      <td>sun</td>
      <td>mon</td>
      <td>tue</td>
      <td>wed</td>
      <td>thu</td>
      <td>fri</td>
      <td>sat</td>
    </table>
    <div id="cal-frame">
      <table class="curr">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td class="nil"></td><td class="nil"></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
          <tr><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td class="today">11</td><td>12</td></tr>
          <tr><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td></tr>
          <tr><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td></tr>
          <tr><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td class="nil"></td><td class="nil"></td><td class="nil"></td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
#cal {
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin:50px auto;
    font: 13px/1.5 Helvatica, Arial, san-serif;
    display:table;
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
}

#cal .header {
    cursor:default;
    background: #cd310d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
    background: #32CD32;
    height: 34px;
    position: relative;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0 #87260C;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cal .header span {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:34px;
}

#cal .header .button {
    width:24px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
#cal .header .left.button {
    left:0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
#cal .header .right.button {
    right:0;
    top:0;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#cal .header .button:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d94215, #bb330f);
    background: #fff;
    color:#808080;
}

#cal .header .month-year {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#cal table {
    background:#fff;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#cal td {
    height:25%;
    width: 17%;
    color:#2b2b2b;
    position:relative;
    line-height:30px;
    /*text-align:center;*/
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    cursor:default;
}
#cal #days td {
    height:26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:90%;
    color:#9e9e9e;
}
#cal #days td:not(:last-child) {
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
}

#cal #cal-frame td.today {
    background:#cccccc;
    color:black;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
}
#cal #cal-frame td:not(.nil):hover {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: #6C1A07 0px -1px;
    background:#CD310D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
    background: #8c8c8c;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px;
}

#cal #cal-frame td span {
    font-size:80%;
    position:relative;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span:first-child {
    bottom:5px;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span:last-child {
    top:5px;
}

#cal #cal-frame table.curr {
    float:left;
}
#cal #cal-frame table.temp {
    position:absolute;
}
```

I want the boxes to be even and fill the full calendar (they currently do not do so). Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hey Change the following CSS into

Old One :

```
#cal td {
    height:25%;
    width: 17%;
    color:#2b2b2b;
    position:relative;
    line-height:30px;
    /*text-align:center;*/
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    cursor:default;
}
```

New One :

```
\#cal td {
height:25%;
        width: 1%;
        color:#2b2b2b;
        position:relative;
        line-height:30px;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
        cursor:default;
    }
```

Note the change of text-align and width.

Comment: Awesome. That fixed the width thing. The height still is not adjusting to fit the calendar. I tried adjusting the height to one percent as well but that did not fix it.

Comment: HI @CassidyHaas .... Do you want to show the calendar in the whole page or some other height is needed for the calender?

Comment: The calendar is not necessarily the whole page. It depends on use input from radio buttons (i have that part figured out fine) I currently have the calendar div defined as a percentage height/width of the page, and the css for that works, like the heading spans the calendar and the border is visible and everything, the blocks of the calendar just won't fill it fit the calendar. Does that make sense?